# Why aren't Persistent types instances of ToJSON/FromJSON in Yesod?

Tags: haskell, yesod, aeson

It's not *that* hard to write ToJSON/FromJSON instances for the generated types but still, while you're generating code could you throw that in? Or is there an easy way to make this happen as a Yesod user? (I haven't dug too deep into how TH works...)

**Update:** 
OK, I like this suggestion but, say my persistent type is User. If I use

```
$(deriveJSON id ''User)
```

it yields

```
  Exception when trying to run compile-time code:
  Data.Aeson.TH.withType: Unsupported type: TySynD Model.User [] (AppT (ConT Model.UserGeneric) (ConT Database.Persist.GenericSql.Raw.SqlPersist))
  Code: deriveJSON (id) 'User
```

apparently because it's an alias. But

```
$(deriveJSON id ''UserGeneric)
```

yields

```
Kind mis-match
The first argument of `UserGeneric' should have kind `(* -> *)
                                                      -> *
                                                      -> *',
but `backend[i5XB]' has kind `*'
```

I've probably still got the wrong type but I can't find enough about what Persistent generates to get the right incantation.

Comment: Have you figured this out yet?  Running into the exact same problem here.

Comment: I haven't been working with Yesod for quite a while now but I'm pretty sure I had this working using the added "json" mentioned in Michael Snoyman's link: https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/wiki/Persistent-entity-syntax#json-instances

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I actually think we'll be adding this feature to Persistent 0.8 (to be released with Yesod 0.10 in a week or two). It's true what dflemstr said about dependency bloat, which is why we haven't done this in the past, but we already depend on aeson now for our configuration types (based on Yaml config files, which uses aeson's data types).

Comment: Thanks Michael, sounds good to me. In the meantime if anyone knows the right syntax for the deriveJSON call that would also be helpful!

Comment: This has been implemented for a while, see: https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/wiki/Persistent-entity-syntax#json-instances

Comment: Thanks Michael! This is awesome stuff. It would be great if you updated the online chapter of your book about RESTful content to include this fact. I'm working from the paper copy, but I check all the examples online for just this reason.

Answer (score 10):

For anyone who doesn't notice the sub comment on Michael Snowman's post, in resent versions of persistent you can do:

```
Person json
    name Text
    age Int
```

and get ToJSON and FromJSON instances of Person.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the automatic deriving mechanism in [`Data.Aeson.TH`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/aeson/latest/doc/html/Data-Aeson-TH.html).

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
$(deriveJSON id ''Foo)
```

This should work fine on both Yesod-generated data types as well as your own types.

It takes a function to customize the record field names. Here, I've just passed `id` to get them unchanged. [See the documentation for details](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/aeson/latest/doc/html/Data-Aeson-TH.html).

Comment: Thanks, looks like both of you had the same answer at the same time.  Yesod types are aliases though so it generates an "Unsupported type" error. I tried using $(deriveJSON id ''UserGeneric) where my type is User, and got this:  

Kind mis-match
    The first argument of `UserGeneric' should have kind `(* -> *)
                                                          -> *
                                                          -> *',
    but `backend[i5XB]' has kind `*'

Answer (score 1):

The default Yesod type generators shouldn't generate `ToJSON`/`FromJSON` instances, because that would add a dependency on `aeson` even if you didn't want to use that package, which could lead to dependency bloat.

You can import `Data.Aeson.TH` and use this code to automatically create JSON instances:

```
data MyDataType = ...

deriveJSON id ''MyDataType
```

Replace `id` with a function that renames fields for you, if you don't want the same field names in Haskell as in the JSON file.